# Rancher server not finding the rancher agent on same server

Tags: docker, rancher

**Issue**

So my problem is that I can't get the rancher server to find the rancher agent. I've looked at the Rancher Troubleshooting FAQs but that haven't helped with my issue. I'm using one server for both the rancher server and the agent and I'm setting the CATTLE_AGENT_IP to the IP of the physical server.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and docker 1.12.3.

**Iptables**

At first I thought it might be a firewall issue, but I've tried disabled it and no luck.

[image]

**Logs**

Rancher agent error log message

```
time="2016-10-27T11:56:50Z" level="info" msg="Host not registered yet. Sleeping 1 second and trying again." Attempt=5 reportedUuid="492dc65c-6359-4a40-b6e3-89c6da704ffb"
```

I feel like I've tried everything without any result. Anyone have an idea what could be wrong or how I could continue to troubleshoot the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. The problem was a faulty `CATTLE_AGENT_IP`. Apparently you can not have `http://` before the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Are you reusing the host from a previous Rancher install?
If so, there is sometimes old credentials that are tried instead of the new ones for the host. The files are in `/var/lib/rancher`. (they are .files so you need ls -a to view)

If you are using a self signed SSL cert it will fail to register if you are not bind mounting the CA root cert. See http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/v1.2/en/installing-rancher/installing-server/basic-ssl-config/ the last section "Adding Hosts" for more info.